# Gap ontop of listview widget

Tags: flutter

I have a gap ontop of a listview sliver bar. The bar slides until the top and then there is a gap.

The listview widget is definitely the issue. I have tried alot of the solutions suggested. Remove padding doesnt work,wrapping in safespace doesn't work, wrapping in media query remove padding doesn't work, edgeinset.zero doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a fix?

```
class Brandspage extends StatelessWidget {
  const Brandspage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 4,
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Brands')),
          body: NestedScrollView(
            headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
              return <Widget>[
                SliverAppBar(
                  automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                  expandedHeight: 400.0,
                  floating: true,
                  pinned: true,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
                  flexibleSpace: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(Tsizes.s),
                    child: ListView(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(height: Tsizes.spacebtwitems),
                          const Tsearchbar(text: 'search for brands'),
                          const SizedBox(height: Tsizes.spacebtwitems),
                          const Theadingbar(
                            text: 'Featured brands',
                            showbutton: true,
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: Tsizes.spacebtwitems),
                          Tgridlayout(
                              itemcount: 6,
                              itembuilder: (_, index) =>
                                  const brandpane(height: 70, showborder: true),
                              lengthofgrid: 56),
                          /* GridView.builder(
                              itemCount: 4,
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              gridDelegate:
                                  const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                                      childAspectRatio: 1,
                                      crossAxisSpacing: 16,
                                      mainAxisSpacing: 16,
                                      mainAxisExtent: 56),
                              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                return const brandpane(
                                  height: 70,
                                  showborder: true,
                                );
                              }),*/
                        ]),
                  ),
                  bottom: const Ttabbar(
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(child: Text('Sport')),
                      Tab(child: Text('Furniture')),
                      Tab(child: Text('Electronics')),
                      Tab(child: Text('Groceries'))
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ];
            },
            body: const TabBarView(
              children: [
                Ttabbarview(),
                Ttabbarview(),
                Ttabbarview(),
                Ttabbarview()
              ],
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}

class Ttabbarview extends StatelessWidget {
  const Ttabbarview({
    super.key,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                const brandshowcasecard(images: [
                  Timages.cardimage,
                  Timages.cardimage2,
                  Timages.cardimage3
                ]),
                const SizedBox(height: Tsizes.spacebtwitems),
                const Theadingbar(
                  text: 'You may also like',
                  showbutton: true,
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: Tsizes.spacebtwitems),
                Tgridlayout(
                    lengthofgrid: 300,
                    itemcount: 4,
                    itembuilder: (_, index) => const ProductCarddiscounts()),
                const SizedBox(height: Tsizes.spacebtwitems)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]);
  }
}
```